# Float: right & float: left;

Tags: css3

Верстаю шаблон со всеми фичами css3 и вот встретился уже с проблемой. Если разрешение по ширине 1980 пикселей (как у меня), то все нормально. А если меньше - то все съезжает.

- Сам шаблон -
     http://bifot.ru/cloud/template/index.html

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно. Хотя, вы сами поймете, в чем беда, когда
   зайдете по ссылкам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `#logo` и `#header_right` ширина в пикселях, в сумме 1534 + 2px бордеров, а вот у `#header 80%`, хотя указана максимальная ширина, лучше указать 100% и `max-width: 1536px` (1534 + 2px бордеров), хотя если экран будет меньше 1536px, всё равно поплывет,  тут или делать всё в %? Или задавать всё жёстко?

Или не все задавать жёстко (оптимально, тогда `#header` не трогать, `#logo` не трогать, а вот у `#header` убрать float, вообще, убрать ширину (тоже вообще ) и указать `margin-left: 300px` (ширина #logo) в IE 11, FF и Google Chrome работало точно)

Comment: Кстати, это не CSS 3.

Comment: css3 там все фишки: тень, боред-радиус и тд)

Comment: Да, но если б его не было, проблема бы осталась. )) Он тут ни при чем. )